# My Juniper router do not have j-web configuration

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

I follow [Juniper docs](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/installation/j-web-software-install.html):

I want to set up the j-web. but in my Junos do not have `set system services web-management http`.

```
admin@MX480-RE0# set system services ?      
Possible completions:
  <[Enter]>            Execute this command
+ apply-groups         Groups from which to inherit configuration data
+ apply-groups-except  Don't inherit configuration data from these groups
> database-replication  Database replication configuration
> dhcp-local-server    Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol server configuration
> extensible-subscriber-services  Extensible Subscriber Services Configuration
> extension-service    Enable JUNOS extension services
> finger               Allow finger requests from remote systems
> flow-tap-dtcp        Configure DTCP-based Flow-tap service
> ftp                  Allow FTP file transfers
> netconf              Allow NETCONF connections
> outbound-ssh         Initiate outbound SSH connection
> packet-triggered-subscribers  Packet Triggered Subscribers configuration
> resource-monitor     Resource monitor configuration
> rest                 Allow RPC execution over HTTP(S) connection
> service-deployment   Configuration for Service Deployment (SDXD) management application
> ssh                  Allow ssh access
> static-subscribers   Static Subscriber Client configuration
> subscriber-management  Subscriber management configuration
> subscriber-management-helper  Subscriber management helper configuration
> telnet               Allow telnet login
> tftp-server          Enable TFTP file transfers
> xnm-clear-text       Allow clear text-based JUNOScript connections
> xnm-ssl              Allow SSL-based JUNOScript connections
  |                    Pipe through a command
{master}[edit]
```

my MX480 version is:

```
Hostname: LA-MX-RE0
Model: mx480
Junos: 15.1F7.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

j-web is not available for the MX platform, as the page you refer to explicitly states:

> Supported Platforms
>
> - SRX Series
> - vSRX

Comment: I see a post say mx480 support j-web. https://community.juniper.net/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MID=70351#bmbfe11a11-8aff-428b-9725-68456c7a83bf

Comment: I doubt it's correct. The document you originally linked says j-web is only supported on SRX, and I don't see any j-web downloads for the MX platform on Juniper's website. Just because someone mentions it on a forum on the internet doesn't make it true.